# Program to find what predicates are missing for a goal to be provable

Tags: prolog, metaprogramming

The program at the bottom is supposed to return clauses that are missing for a goal, in this case `p(1, 3, fire)` to be provable.

The problem is that it returns one solution “too many” as shown in the last solution in this output:

```
?- main.
MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,2,johnDroppedAMatch)
true ;

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,1,johnWasTired)
true ;

MISSING PREMISES:
precedes(3,3)
p(A,3,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,2,johnWasTired)
true ;
false.
```

What I would like is just:

```
MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,2,johnDroppedAMatch)
true ;

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,1,johnWasTired)
true ;
```

I have a hard time understanding what’s wrong and would appreciate some tips for improving it :-), or maybe some literature tips (i am already familiar with [Markus Triska](https://www.metalevel.at/)'s excellent page).

The important predicate is `missing0(G, M)`, where `G` is a goal and `M` a list of missing clauses. One of my suspicions about the problem is that there is a potentially infinite number of clauses that fail, so I am missing some kind of "stopping" condition.

I posted the same [question](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/program-that-returns-what-clauses-are-missing-for-a-goal-to-succeed/1639) on the SWI Prolog forum but did not get any responses. I am running SWI Prolog.

```
% https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/clp/clpr.pl

:-use_module(library(clpr)).

% time is ordered

precedes(1, 2).
precedes(2, 3).

% knowledge

p(X1, T2, johnDroppedAMatch):-
    p(X2, T1, johnWasTired),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.5 * X2}.

p(X1, T2, fire):-
    p(X2, T1, presenceOfFlammableMaterial),
    p(X3, T1, johnDroppedAMatch),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.7 * X2 * X3}.

% --- Reasoning about knowledge

missing(G, M) :- call(G), 
                 M = ['There are no missing premises.'].

missing(G, M) :- \+clause(G, _),
                 M = ['There are no clauses for the goal.'].

missing(G, M) :- clause(G, B), \+G, missing0(B, M).

% -- Look for missing clauses in a conjunction

missing0(G, M) :- G = (G1, G2), !, 
                  missing0(G1, M1), missing0(G2, M2), append(M1, M2, M).

% -- Look for missing clauses in a disjunction 

missing0(G, M) :- G = (G1; _), missing0(G1, M). 

% -- Look for missing clauses in a disjunction

missing0(G, M) :- G = (_; G2), missing0(G2, M). 

% -- If G is callable then it is not missing

missing0(G, M) :- call(G), M = []. 

% G fails, and is neither a conjunction nor a disjunction, so
% put in in M. Here I collect missing clauses.

missing0(G, M) :- \+G, G \= (_, _), G \= (_; _), M = [G]. 

% If G fails and if B is in the body of G, check what predicates are
% missing for B to be provable. G \= {_} is to avoid an error when
% using clause/2 on clpr predicates.

missing0(G, M) :- \+G, G \= {_}, clause(G, B), missing0(B, M). 


showMissing(M) :- copy_term_nat(M, M1), 
                  numbervars(M1, 0, _, [attvar(bind)]),
                  sort(M1, M2), 
                  nl, writeln('MISSING PREMISES:'),
                  maplist(writeln, M2).

main :- missing(p(1, 3, fire), M), showMissing(M).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not an answer, but I have played around a bit with the code, added some printout and made it rather deterministic. It now reports a single solution.

## Original code, slightly reviewed

Here is the original code, with some printouts. It reports exactly as previously, with the output not sorted to be able to trace what it hits first.

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).

% ======================
% knowledge
% ======================

% time is ordered
% Note: Time is not transitive as precedes(1,3) is missing!

precedes(1, 2).
precedes(2, 3).

p(X1, T2, johnDroppedAMatch):-
    p(X2, T1, johnWasTired),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.5 * X2}.

p(X1, T2, fire):-
    p(X2, T1, presenceOfFlammableMaterial),
    p(X3, T1, johnDroppedAMatch),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.7 * X2 * X3}.

% ======================
% reasoning about knowledge
% ======================

% Note: What exactly does it mean for a premise to be "missing"?
% Are variables to be resolved when reporting? 

missing(G, M) :- call(G), 
                 M = ['There are no missing premises.'].

missing(G, M) :- \+clause(G, _),
                 M = ['There are no clauses for the goal.'].

missing(G, M) :- clause(G, B), \+G, missingr(B, M, 0).

% --- Recursively look for missing stuff in a goal 
% D is the Depth of the analysis
% SP is a string of spaces for indentation

missingr(G, M, D) :- G = (G1, G2), !,
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» AND «~w»\n",[SP,G1,G2]), spinc(D,DP),
                     missingr(G1, M1, DP), 
                     missingr(G2, M2, DP),                  
                     append(M1, M2, M).

missingr(G, M, D) :- G = (G1; _), !,
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» OR «~w»\n",[SP,G1,"..."]), spinc(D,DP),
                     missingr(G1, M, DP).

missingr(G, M, D) :- G = (_ ; G2), !,
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» OR «~w»\n",[SP,"...",G2]), spinc(D,DP),
                     missingr(G2, M, DP).

missingr(G, M, D) :- sp(D,SP), format("~wMaybe «~w» can be called?\n",[SP,G]),
                     call(G),
                     format("~w«~w» succeeds; nothing is missing here.\n",[SP,G]),
                     M = [].

missingr(G, M, D) :- \+G, G \= (_,_), G \= (_;_),
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is not provable, not a conjunction, not a disjunction: Consider missing!\n",[SP,G]),
                     M = [G].

missingr(G, M, D) :- \+G, G \= {_}, clause(G, B),
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is not provable, not a constraint, and a clause with body «~w», continue with body\n",[SP,G,B]), spinc(D,DP),
                     missingr(B, M, DP).

% Igniter

showMissing(M) :- copy_term_nat(M, M1), 
                  numbervars(M1, 0, _, [attvar(bind)]),
                  % sort(M1, M2), % do not sort so that terms are output in found order
                  M2 =  M1,
                  nl, writeln('MISSING PREMISES:'),
                  maplist(writeln, M2).

main :- missing(p(1, 3, fire), M), showMissing(M).


% Generate string of N spaces fast. 

spinc(In,Out) :- Out is In+2.

sp(0,"") :- !.
sp(1,".") :- !.
sp(Len,Str) :- Len > 1,
               Lenx is Len div 2, Remx is Len rem 2, 
               sp(Lenx,Strx), 
               string_concat(Strx,Strx,Stry),
               (Remx == 0 -> Str = Stry ; string_concat(Stry,".",Str)),!.
```

#### Ouput

```
?- main.  
«p(_7002,_7004,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» AND «p(_7010,_7004,johnDroppedAMatch),precedes(_7004,3),{1=0.7*_7002*_7010}»
..Maybe «p(_7002,_7004,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» can be called?
..«p(_7002,_7004,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» is not provable, not a conjunction, not a disjunction: Consider missing!
..«p(_7010,_7004,johnDroppedAMatch)» AND «precedes(_7004,3),{1=0.7*_7002*_7010}»
....Maybe «p(_7010,_7004,johnDroppedAMatch)» can be called?
....«p(_7010,_7004,johnDroppedAMatch)» is not provable, not a conjunction, not a disjunction: Consider missing!
....«precedes(_7004,3)» AND «{1=0.7*_7002*_7010}»
......Maybe «precedes(_7004,3)» can be called?
......«precedes(2,3)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
......Maybe «{1=0.7*_7002*_7010}» can be called?
......«{1=0.7*_7914*_7940}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,2,johnDroppedAMatch)
true ;

....«p(_7010,_7004,johnDroppedAMatch)» is not provable, not a constraint, and a clause with body «p(_7278,_7280,johnWasTired),precedes(_7280,_7004),{_7010=0.5*_7278}», continue with body
......«p(_7278,_7280,johnWasTired)» AND «precedes(_7280,_7004),{_7010=0.5*_7278}»
........Maybe «p(_7278,_7280,johnWasTired)» can be called?
........«p(_7278,_7280,johnWasTired)» is not provable, not a conjunction, not a disjunction: Consider missing!
........«precedes(_7280,_7004)» AND «{_7010=0.5*_7278}»
..........Maybe «precedes(_7280,_7004)» can be called?
..........«precedes(1,2)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
..........Maybe «{_7010=0.5*_7278}» can be called?
..........«{_8266=0.5*_8368}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
....«precedes(2,3)» AND «{1=0.7*_7002*_8266}»
......Maybe «precedes(2,3)» can be called?
......«precedes(2,3)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
......Maybe «{1=0.7*_7002*_8266}» can be called?
......«{1=0.7*_9472*_8266}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,1,johnWasTired)
true ;

..........«precedes(2,3)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
..........Maybe «{_7010=0.5*_7278}» can be called?
..........«{_8266=0.5*_8368}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
....«precedes(3,3)» AND «{1=0.7*_7002*_8266}»
......Maybe «precedes(3,3)» can be called?
......«precedes(3,3)» is not provable, not a conjunction, not a disjunction: Consider missing!
......Maybe «{1=0.7*_7002*_8266}» can be called?
......«{1=0.7*_9476*_8266}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,3,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,2,johnWasTired)
precedes(3,3)
true ;
false.
```

Thinking about this, it becomes unclear what is meant by *"a predicate is missing"*, or even what is supposed to happen in case a conjunction or disjunction is encountered during interpretation. Needs more detail!

## Modified code attempt

Here is modified code, which seems to be along the line of what is wanted but which more deterministic, outputting just one solution:

```
:-use_module(library(clpr)).

% ======================
% knowledge
% ======================

% time is ordered
% Note: Time is not transitive as precedes(1,3) is missing!

precedes(1, 2).
precedes(2, 3).

p(X1, T2, johnDroppedAMatch):-
    p(X2, T1, johnWasTired),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.5 * X2}.

p(X1, T2, fire):-
    p(X2, T1, presenceOfFlammableMaterial),
    p(X3, T1, johnDroppedAMatch),
    precedes(T1, T2),
    {X1 = 0.7 * X2 * X3}.

% ======================
% reasoning about knowledge
% ======================

% Note: What exactly does it mean for a premise to be "missing"?
% Are variables to be resolved when reporting? 

missing(G, M) :- call(G), 
                 M = ['There are no missing premises.'].

missing(G, M) :- \+clause(G, _),
                 M = ['There are no clauses for the goal.'].

missing(G, M) :- clause(G, B), \+G, missingr(B, M, 0).

% --- Recursively look for missing stuff in a goal

% Conjunction
% In a conjunction we can fail on left or right, go down both branches.

missingr(G, M, D) :- G = (G1, G2), !,
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» AND «~w»\n",[SP,G1,G2]), spinc(D,DP),
                     missingr(G1, M1, DP), 
                     missingr(G2, M2, DP),                  
                     append(M1, M2, M).

% Disjunction. Finagle a proper guard!
% Note: In a disjunction we fail if we fail on both sides, but then what to report???

missingr(G, M, D) :- G = (G1; G2), !,
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» OR «~w»\n",[SP,G1,G2]), spinc(D,DP),
                     (missingr(G1, M, DP) ; missingr(G2, M, DP)).

% If G is callable and succeeds then it is not missing. 
% The call will unify variables, which may or may not be what we want.

missingr(G, M, D) :- sp(D,SP), format("~wMaybe «~w» can be called?\n",[SP,G]),
                     call(G), !,
                     format("~w«~w» succeeds; nothing is missing here.\n",[SP,G]),
                     M = [].

% If G fails and if B is the body of G, check what predicates are
% missing for B to be provable. G \= {_} is to avoid an error when
% using clause/2 on clpr predicates.

missingr(G, M, D) :- \+G, !, 
                     sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is nonprovable\n",[SP,G]), spinc(D,DP),
                     nonprovable(G, M, DP).

nonprovable(G, M, D) :- G \= {_}, clause(G, B), !,
                        sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is a nonprovable clause with body «~w», continue with body\n",[SP,G,B]), spinc(D,DP),
                        missingr(B, M, DP). 

nonprovable(G, M, D) :- G \= {_}, !,
                        sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is a nonprovable non-clause: considered missing!\n",[SP,G]),
                        M = [G].

nonprovable(G, M, D) :- sp(D,SP), format("~w«~w» is a constraint; dropped!\n",[SP,G]),
                        M = [].

% Igniter

showMissing(M) :- copy_term_nat(M, M1), 
                  numbervars(M1, 0, _, [attvar(bind)]),
                  nl, writeln('MISSING PREMISES:'),
                  maplist(writeln, M1).

main :- missing(p(1, 3, fire), M), showMissing(M).


% Generate string of N spaces fast. 

spinc(In,Out) :- Out is In+2.

sp(0,"") :- !.
sp(1,".") :- !.
sp(Len,Str) :- Len > 1,
               Lenx is Len div 2, Remx is Len rem 2, 
               sp(Lenx,Strx), 
               string_concat(Strx,Strx,Stry),
               (Remx == 0 -> Str = Stry ; string_concat(Stry,".",Str)),!.
```

#### New Output

Running it generates a single solution:

```
?- main.
«p(_5182,_5184,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» AND «p(_5190,_5184,johnDroppedAMatch),precedes(_5184,3),{1=0.7*_5182*_5190}»
..Maybe «p(_5182,_5184,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» can be called?
..«p(_5182,_5184,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» is nonprovable
....«p(_5182,_5184,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)» is a nonprovable non-clause: considered missing!
..«p(_5190,_5184,johnDroppedAMatch)» AND «precedes(_5184,3),{1=0.7*_5182*_5190}»
....Maybe «p(_5190,_5184,johnDroppedAMatch)» can be called?
....«p(_5190,_5184,johnDroppedAMatch)» is nonprovable
......«p(_5190,_5184,johnDroppedAMatch)» is a nonprovable clause with body «p(_5572,_5574,johnWasTired),precedes(_5574,_5184),{_5190=0.5*_5572}», 
........«p(_5572,_5574,johnWasTired)» AND «precedes(_5574,_5184),{_5190=0.5*_5572}»
..........Maybe «p(_5572,_5574,johnWasTired)» can be called?
..........«p(_5572,_5574,johnWasTired)» is nonprovable
............«p(_5572,_5574,johnWasTired)» is a nonprovable non-clause: considered missing!
..........«precedes(_5574,_5184)» AND «{_5190=0.5*_5572}»
............Maybe «precedes(_5574,_5184)» can be called?
............«precedes(1,2)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
............Maybe «{_5190=0.5*_5572}» can be called?
............«{_6626=0.5*_6728}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
....«precedes(2,3)» AND «{1=0.7*_5182*_6626}»
......Maybe «precedes(2,3)» can be called?
......«precedes(2,3)» succeeds; nothing is missing here.
......Maybe «{1=0.7*_5182*_6626}» can be called?
......«{1=0.7*_7658*_6626}» succeeds; nothing is missing here.

MISSING PREMISES:
p(A,2,presenceOfFlammableMaterial)
p(B,1,johnWasTired)
true.
```

But as said, what do we actually want to have here?

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at this :-) This seems to be the solution. That G is a non-provable non-clause indeed seems important.